# "User-defined literal operator not found"

Tags: c++

I'm reading the CppCoreGuidelines Philosophy, and have found an example that I don't understand. (https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-philosophy)

The codeexample says;

```
change_speed(double s);   // bad: what does s signify?
// ...
change_speed(2.3);

change_speed(Speed s);    // better: the meaning of s is specified
// ...
change_speed(2.3);        // error: no unit
change_speed(23m / 10s);  // meters per second
```

My question is regarding the last line. I'm assuming that the guidelines recommends defining Speed like this;

```
typedef int Speed;
```

but in the final line in the example they are using m and s as part of the arguments. If I try the same I just get an error saying "user-defined literal operator not found".

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: A typedef is no better than using `double` directly. It may make your code readable (arguably), but it adds nothing in terms of type safety, you can still pass `2.3`. Only a class `Speed` with explicit constructors can add type safety.

Comment: http://blog.m-ou.se/2013/09/29/compile-time-unit-arithmetic.html

Comment: It should be`23_m` and `10_s`.  For user defined literal, did you try entering the term into a seach engine?

Comment: @StoryTeller The example on the web page doesn't say how `Speed` is defined, I guess we're supposed to figure out that it's a class, because of the error in the 2nd to last line.

Comment: @Barmar - User defined literals are all about type safety. And self documentation is fine, but I prefer it if the compiler could catch such errors. [In their book](https://www.amazon.com/Template-Metaprogramming-Concepts-Techniques-Beyond/dp/0321227255), Abrahams and Gurtovoy present how to leverage the type system to get compiler errors for unit mistakes in scientific programming. And [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) does something similar.

Comment: @Barmar - We are strongly led to believe it's a class (it doesn't have to be, since dividing `m` by `s` could be overloaded to return a plain double, but it's unlikely).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is regarding the last line. I'm assuming that the guidelines recommends defining Speed like this;
>
> ```
> typedef int Speed;
> ```

Nope.  They are expecting something like:

```
class Speed {
    double value;
public:
    ....
}

class Distance {
     double value;
public:
     ...
};

class Time {
     double value;
public:
     ....
};

Speed operator /(Distance d, Time t);
```

and a pair of user defined literal operators for Distance and Time

```
Distance operator "" _m(double);

Time operator "" _s(double);
```

There is a bug in the example though.  It should be:

```
change_speed(23_m / 10_s);  // meters per second
```

Comment: Thanks, the only change I had to make to your example was to define the operators to use 'long double' instead of 'double', and in the call to change_speed I used 23.0_m instead of 23_m.